# How is this perspective called

Tags: 2d-games, isometric, orthographic

"Hyper Light Drifter" and other games have an pseudo isometric perspective:

[image]

How is this perspective called? Are there any "rules" to it that i can look up ?

Thanks.

Comment: I like `pseudo-isometric`... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general term is *axonometric* projection.

"[Although there are countless possible axonometric projections](http://www.compuphase.com/axometr.htm), only two are standardized for technical drawings."  Your screen shot falls into one of the "countless possible" kinds.